# Flash upload only 2 files on domain at time, FileReference.upload limitations

Tags: flash, upload, filereference

I am creating flash uploader and want to start 10 uploadings at time.
But flash upload only 2 files on domain at time, other references wait for something.

In IE with ActiveX Player limitation is about 6 files at time.

Is there any ideas how to change this limitation?
For uploading I need to use FileReference.upload without creating URLRequest object from file data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this once a long time ago and found no way around this. The restriction actually isn't because of Flash at all, but rather the application/browser running Flash. Any net connection request or push happens through the API of the Flash Player and it's running environment. However, I might have a suggestion to solve the problem. Try creating 10 subdomains on your site that all point to the same server and have the upload logic use each one of the domains for the upload. This 'should' trick the browser/system to allow additional uploads as the restriction is domain based (I think).
Hope this helps!